# How can I get the latest 10 posts those are written by people in my network (2 level) with gremlin query?

Tags: graph, orientdb, gremlin

I have friends, my friends have friends also. How can I get the latest 10 posts those are written by people in my network (2 level) with gremlin query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you want to obtain the last 10 posts of friends and friends of friends of user `u1`:

```
u1.out('friend').copySplit(_().out('friend').except([u1]).out('post'), _().out('post')).exhaustMerge.dedup.order{it.b.ts <=> it.a.ts}[0..<10].map
```

gives you:

```
==>{msg=f, ts=2015-03-08 12:09:11.567}
==>{msg=e, ts=2015-03-08 12:09:01.459}
==>{msg=d, ts=2015-03-08 12:08:56.339}
==>{msg=c, ts=2015-03-08 12:08:41.209}
==>{msg=b, ts=2015-03-08 12:08:21.086}
```

with the following sample graph:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

g = new TinkerGraph()
u1 = g.addVertex('user1')
u2 = g.addVertex('user2')
u3 = g.addVertex('user3')
u4 = g.addVertex('user4')
u5 = g.addVertex('user5')

g.addEdge(u1,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u1,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u3,'friend')
g.addEdge(u3,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u1,u3,'friend')
g.addEdge(u3,u1,'friend')
g.addEdge(u2,u4,'friend')
g.addEdge(u4,u2,'friend')
g.addEdge(u4,u5,'friend')
g.addEdge(u5,u4,'friend')

p1 = g.addVertex('post1',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 100000), 'msg':'a'])
p2 = g.addVertex('post2',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 80000), 'msg':'b'])
p3 = g.addVertex('post3',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 60000), 'msg':'c'])
p4 = g.addVertex('post4',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 45000), 'msg':'d'])
p5 = g.addVertex('post5',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 40000), 'msg':'e'])
p6 = g.addVertex('post6',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 30000), 'msg':'f'])
p7 = g.addVertex('post7',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 20000), 'msg':'g'])
p8 = g.addVertex('post8',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000), 'msg':'h'])
p9 = g.addVertex('post9',['ts': new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), 'msg':'i'])

g.addEdge(u1,p1,'post')
g.addEdge(u1,p9,'post')
g.addEdge(u2,p3,'post')
g.addEdge(u3,p6,'post')
g.addEdge(u4,p5,'post')
g.addEdge(u4,p2,'post')
g.addEdge(u4,p4,'post')
g.addEdge(u5,p7,'post')
g.addEdge(u5,p8,'post')
```

Comment: sorry @Faber I want to get my friends' posts also, could you add this to your answer..